# JQuery function does not work after changing ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown, slideup

I have a simple file that has a Jquery script it in that looks like this:

```
<script type="text\javascript">     
$('.grey_title').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.inner_div').slideToggle('slow');
    });
    $('#hideall').click(function(){
        $('.inner_div').slideUp('slow');
        $(this).parent().html("<span id=\"showall\">Show all Menus</span>");
    });
    $('#showall').click(function(){
        $('.inner_div').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).parent().html("<span id=\"hideall\">Hide all Menus</span>");
    });
   });
</script>
  <div><span id="hideall">Hide all Menus</span></div>
```

The function works fine while hiding menus and when you change the ID to showall in the HTML and the script to slideToggle, however when you click Hide all it will close all and according to Firefox, changes the item to be

```
<span id="showall">...</span>
```

but, when clicked again it does nothing.  What could I be doing wrong?

the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the binding to fail since there is no showall when the binding is done

A better choice is to [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

You may want to switch the functions around to match what is shown when the page loads

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kuuHP/)

```
$('#hideall').toggle(
  function(){
    $('.inner_div').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).text("Show all Menus");
  },
  function(){
    $('.inner_div').slideDown('slow');
    $(this).text("Hide all Menus");
  }
);
```

Comment: Toggle would be probably the best choice.

Comment: @Travis So if Toggle is the best choice, how come you accept the other answer?

Comment: @Travis Pessetto: If you think this answer is better, you really should "un-accept" the other one and then accept this one.

Comment: i originally accepted mridkash's solution because for a beginner, which I am, it is much more easy to understand why the problem exists in the first place, while I accept understand your code is the best solution in most cases, I would have no idea when binding would have been done, as I expected it to be constantly going, while mridkash's solution points out more explicitly that when anything happens to anything it detaches, which is true of even when it is there then removed and replaced with the same element.

Comment: @Travis. Understood. Thanks for the accept. I also believe that the showall click would never have happened since there was no element with ID=showall at the moment the click event was assigned. Easy enough to check in firebug with your original code. Have a great evening. Bedtime here now.

Answer (score 2):

When the id is gone, it detaches the event bound to it. You can try the `live` event binding.

```
$('#hideall').live('click', function(){
    $('.inner_div').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).parent().html("<span id=\"showall\">Show all Menus</span>");
});
$('#showall').live('click', function(){
    $('.inner_div').slideDown('slow');
    $(this).parent().html("<span id=\"hideall\">Hide all Menus</span>");
});
```

Comment: @Travis Pessetto:  While using `live()` solves the specific problem within _your_ code,  @mplungjan really has the **best** solution where his code is simpler, cleaner and much more efficient.

Comment: I was going to post this. The 'live' trick is just that, a trick. @mplungjan's way is more elegant.

Comment: @Travis Pessetto, @mplungjan: Everyone agrees that `toggle` is the better solution... you should fix this by accepting the answer by @mplungjan instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegate or live to define the events. What the events above do is only bind the handler to the existing elements on the page while the live/delegate function bind to existing and future elements.

```
$(document).delegate('.grey_title', "click",function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.inner_div').slideToggle('slow');
 }).delegate('#hideall'."click", function(){
        $('.inner_div').slideUp('slow');
        $(this).parent().html("<span id=\"showall\">Show all Menus</span>");
}).delegate('#showall',"click", function(){
        $('.inner_div').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).parent().html("<span id=\"hideall\">Hide all Menus</span>");
});

</script>
  <div><span id="hideall">Hide all Menus</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the click event to an element that does not yet exist... try this:

```
$('#showall').live('click', function(){
        $('.inner_div').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).parent().html("<span id=\"hideall\">Hide all Menus</span>");
    });
```

Comment: I am assuming that when the inner HTML is changed the bind is destroyed for that element too, so I did it both to showall and the hideall functions.